# Unable to assign class to image on storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have dragged an Image View to my story board, and have created a class called `Logo`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Logo : UIView

@property(strong,nonatomic)UIImageView *logo;

-(void)loadLogo;

@end
```

However, when I try to assign `Logo` class to my Image View on storyboard in Identity inspector, it does not recognize Logo as a legit class and thus I am unable to assign it. Why is this happening? Logo is a subclass of UIView isn't it? How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already answered your question. Your problem is because you want to assign your `Logo` class which is inherited from `UIView`, with a `UIImageView`. This won't work.

You have to assign your View with your class under Identity inspector.

[image]

Then modify `@property(weak,nonatomic) UIImageView IBOutlet *logo;` property, and you can assign it.

Add your View into your VC, then assign your View with `@interface Logo : UIView`, Then modify `@property(weak,nonatomic) UIImageView IBOutlet *logo;` , Add an `UIImageView` to your View in Interface Builder, then you can assign your `IBOutlet *logo;` with the `UIImageView` what you placed there

If you place a UIView on your ViewController, of corse you can assign it with your custom class only if it is inherited from UIView.

If you place a UIImageView on your ViewController, of corse you can assign it with your custom class only if it is inherited from UIImageView.
and so on...

Comment: Yes. It's this step that I couldn't do. When I type in Logo and click enter, it goes back to UIImageView, which means it doesn't recognize that there's a class called Logo at all.

Comment: Because your superclass is UIView, not UIImageView. You have to subclass UIImageView: @interface Logo : UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an IBOutlet

```
UIImageView IBOutlet *logo;
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Drag a `view` object from the objects library and add it to a view in your storyboard.

2 - Select it and set its class to be `Logo`

3 - Add an image view to it

And now you'll be able to assign the image view to be the `logo` outlet.

If the only way you'll be adding `logo` is through storyboard then your interface should look like this :

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *logo;
```